# SQL ignores last values

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try to insert 5 datasets into my database. The SQL is this:

```
INSERT INTO imdb_crawl (id, title, link) VALUES 
('tt3008816', '009-1: The End of the Beginning', 80048948), 
('tt2353767', '1,000 Times Good Night', 80001898), 
('tt2391950', '1000 to 1: The Cory Weissman Story', 80010865), 
('tt2391950', '100 Below Zero', 70273426), 
('tt2290065', '100 Bloody Acres', 70276012) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id;
```

and I get the response "4 lines added". The database is empty. Even with other data, the first dataset won't get saved; but I dont get an error either. Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You're inserting the id `tt2391950` twice, so I suspect the second time is actually updating the existing record (I've never used MySQL, but I assume that's what the `ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` bit does).

Answer (score 2):

You have 3rd and 4th row with the same key:

```
('tt2391950', '1000 to 1: The Cory Weissman Story', 80010865), 
('tt2391950', '100 Below Zero', 70273426),
```

So you only have 4 lines that are added instead of 5.

In your statement you have statement `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id`, but it does nothing in your case, because it updates the value `id` to the same value. You would need to update it to something more meaningful instead, for example:

```
INSERT INTO imdb_crawl (id, title, link) VALUES 
('tt2391950', '1000 to 1: The Cory Weissman Story', 80010865), 
('tt2391950', '100 Below Zero', 70273426), 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 'tt' + link;
```

In this case the `id` of your second row would be `tt70273426`.